# Deep link not redirect properly when app already installed in iOS 13

Tags: ios, objective-c, ios13, ios-universal-links, deeplink

I have use deep link for confirm email in my application. I have manage URL scheme for app open. I have sent confirmation email on user registration. When user click on link mention in that confirmation mail. User should only redirect to application. But in my case when user click on link then user redirect to application as well as redirect to app store.

It's working fine till iOS 12. Currently issue occur in iOS 13 only.

Link url:
http://abc.in/abc/verify/?stud_id=80

Comment: Does your app have SceneDelegate?

Comment: No, I have create this project before 2.5 years.

Comment: @Frankenstein did you find a solution for this?